# Is it possible to use an if condition in PHP on a column/variable declared in MySQL database?

Tags: php, sql, database

I am currently working on a Voting website. I would like to know if I can put an 'if condition' in PHP on a variable that I have defined in MySQL database?
I have a database called 'users.' This database has three columns-username, password and flag. The username and password are pre-defined. 'flag' is set to 0 by default. A 0 value of flag indicates that the user hasn't voted yet. I want to use an 'if condition' on flag to check whether or not the user has already voted. 
The code that I have so far will update the flag to 1, however the if condition doesn't seem to work properly. It could be that I am not reading 'flag' from my database properly. I am also using a cookie to store the username of the user, and then reading that cookie to set flag=1 for that particular user.
All I need to know now is:

1. READ the value of flag from the database and
2. Apply an if condition on flag

Thanks.

EDIT:
I need to take the user to different pages depending on the value of flag. I want the user to go to 'Thank You' for voting page if flag for that particular user is 0, otherwise if flag is 1, I take him to 'You have already voted' page.

Here's the code:

```
<?php

$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="dbxxxxx"; // Mysql username 
$password="password"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="dbxxxxx_users"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="users"; // Table name 


// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$user = $_COOKIE["details"];  //cookie details has the username the user used to log in

$SQL = "SELECT flag FROM users WHERE Username='$user'"; //THIS IS WHERE I AM TRYING TO READ FLAG, HOWEVER IT DOESN'T WORK. I NEED AN ALTERNATE STATEMENT FOR WHAT I AM DOING HERE.
$flag = mysql_query( $SQL );   
$db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($flag);  

if($db_field==0)     {       
        mysql_query("UPDATE result SET Votes=Votes+1 //if flag in database = 0 
        WHERE Name='Candidate1'");  //updates result for candidate1 if the user voted for 1
        $user = $_COOKIE["details"];  //reading the cookie again. can be omitted.

        mysql_query("UPDATE users SET flag=1   //changing flag to 1 so user cannot vote again
        WHERE Username='$user'");

        header("location: http://www.lithuaniavote.com/thankyou.html");
 }

else    //flag != 1 or user has already voted
{
    header("location: http://www.lithuaniavote.com/alreadyvoted.html");
}
?>
```

Comment: Please post your code, table schema, some sample data and what do you expect to see.

Comment: As I do not know your database I cannot answer your questions. Also please give some information so that we have a chance of helping you.

Comment: Please check the code now.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand *why* you need to check the flag on the `PHP` side. You can just add a filter based on the flag.

```
SELECT ... FROM votes WHERE flag = 0
```

Otherwise, are you looking for something like this?

```
$sql = "SELECT flag FROM votes WHERE username = 'bob'";

$result = mysqli_query($sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
if( $row['flag'] == 0 ) {
    //do something
}
```

Comment: I need to take the user to different pages depending on the value of flag. I want the user to go to 'Thank You' for voting page if flag for that particular user is 0, otherwise if flag is 1, I take him to 'You have already voted' page.

Comment: So... do it then? Are you expecting us to write the code for you?

Comment: Well, I was just answering your question - I don't understand why you need to check the flag on the PHP side.

Answer (score 1):

Well, first of all you should select data about user from DB

```
<?php
$flag = false;
// making query text
$query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '".$username."'";    
// executing mysql query
$sel = mysql_query($query);
if ($sel AND mysql_num_rows($sel) >= 1) { // if query was successfully executed
    $row = mysql_fetch_object($sel); // making object ($row) from DB data (now you have $row->username, $row->password and $row->flag)
    $flag = $row->flag; // write flag value from DB into php variable
}

if ($flag != false) {
    // user hadn't wote
    // so we can present voting poll here or execute update query if user just voted
} else {
    // user already woted
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Once Query is ran, This would do it:

```
if( $row['flag'] == 0 ) {
    header('Location: http://www.example.com/thank_you.php');
} else if ($row['flag'] == 1 ) 
    header('Location: http://www.example.com/you_have_voted.php');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with SQL:

```
$sql = "select IF(flag='1','Voted','Not Voted') AS 'status' from users where username='$username'";
```

In the code you would do something like:

```
switch($status){

  case 'Not Voted':
  include('newVoter.php');
  break;

  default:
  include('voted.php');

}
```

If you're not printing anything to screen before the check you can do this:

```
switch($status){

  case 'Not Voted':
  header('Location: newVoter.php');
  break;

  default:
  header('Location: voted.php');

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

if ($stmt = mysqli->prepare("SELECT flag FROM users WHERE username=?")) {

    /* bind params */
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, $user);

    /* execute query */
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    /* bind result variables */
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $flag);

    if($flag != 0) {
       if ($upd = mysqli->prepare("UPDATE users SET flag = 1 WHERE username=?")) {
           mysqli_stmt_bind_param($upd, $user);
           mysqli_stmt_execute($upd);

           /* did not vote. succes view */
       } 
    } else {
      /* voted already. error view  */
    }
}

$mysqli->close();
```